# Magento 2: Not Able to Login As A Customer

Tags: magento2, customer, cache, login, customer-account

When I'm trying to do is **Login As Customer**, it gives the below error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:84:"Invalid method Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor::isLoggedIn(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:11155:"#0 D:\wamp\www\smint\magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\DefaultModel.php(201): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__call('isLoggedIn', Array)
#1 D:\wamp\www\smint\magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\DefaultModel.php(201): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->isLoggedIn()
#2 D:\wamp\www\smint\magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\DefaultModel.php(114): Custom\Module\Model\DefaultModel->_isUserAuth()
```

I have already Cleared Cached & Removed data from **Var** folder

**DefaultModel.php**

/**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model;

/**
 * Implementation of \Zend_Captcha
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class DefaultModel extends \Zend_Captcha_Image implements \Magento\Captcha\Model\CaptchaInterface {

    /**
     * Key in session for captcha code
     */
    const SESSION_WORD = 'word';

    /**
     * Min captcha lengths default value
     */
    const DEFAULT_WORD_LENGTH_FROM = 3;

    /**
     * Max captcha lengths default value
     */
    const DEFAULT_WORD_LENGTH_TO = 5;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_captchaData;

    /**
     * Captcha expire time
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_expiration;

    /**
     * Override default value to prevent a captcha cut off
     * @var int
     * @see \Zend_Captcha_Image::$_fsize
     */
    protected $_fsize = 22;

    /**
     * Captcha form id
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_formId;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory
     */
    protected $_resLogFactory;

    /**
     * Overrides parent parameter as session comes in constructor.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_keepSession = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_session;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session
     * @param \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $captchaData
     * @param \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory $resLogFactory
     * @param string $formId
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session, \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $captchaData, \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory $resLogFactory, $formId
    ) {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_captchaData = $captchaData;
        $this->_resLogFactory = $resLogFactory;
        $this->_formId = $formId;
    }

    /**
     * Returns key with respect of current form ID
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getFormIdKey($key) {
        return $this->_formId . '_' . $key;
    }

    /**
     * Get Block Name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockName() {
        return 'Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha\DefaultCaptcha';
    }

    /**
     * Whether captcha is required to be inserted to this form
     *
     * @param null|string $login
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isRequired($login = null) {
        if ($this->_isUserAuth() && !$this->isShownToLoggedInUser() || !$this->_isEnabled() || !in_array(
                        $this->_formId, $this->_getTargetForms()
                )
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->_isShowAlways() || $this->_isOverLimitAttempts(
                        $login
                ) || $this->_session->getData(
                        $this->_getFormIdKey('show_captcha')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check if CAPTCHA has to be shown to logged in user on this form
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShownToLoggedInUser() {
        $forms = (array) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('shown_to_logged_in_user');
        foreach ($forms as $formId => $isShownToLoggedIn) {
            if ($isShownToLoggedIn && $this->_formId == $formId) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check is over limit attempts
     *
     * @param string $login
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isOverLimitAttempts($login) {
        return $this->_isOverLimitIpAttempt() || $this->_isOverLimitLoginAttempts($login);
    }

    /**
     * Returns number of allowed attempts for same login
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getAllowedAttemptsForSameLogin() {
        return (int) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('failed_attempts_login');
    }

    /**
     * Returns number of allowed attempts from same IP
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getAllowedAttemptsFromSameIp() {
        return (int) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('failed_attempts_ip');
    }

    /**
     * Check is overlimit saved attempts from one ip
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isOverLimitIpAttempt() {
        $countAttemptsByIp = $this->_getResourceModel()->countAttemptsByRemoteAddress();
        return $countAttemptsByIp >= $this->_getAllowedAttemptsFromSameIp();
    }

    /**
     * Is Over Limit Login Attempts
     *
     * @param string $login
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isOverLimitLoginAttempts($login) {
        if ($login != false) {
            $countAttemptsByLogin = $this->_getResourceModel()->countAttemptsByUserLogin($login);
            return $countAttemptsByLogin >= $this->_getAllowedAttemptsForSameLogin();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check is user auth
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isUserAuth() {
        return $this->_session->isLoggedIn();
    }

    /**
     * Whether to respect case while checking the answer
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCaseSensitive() {
        return (string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('case_sensitive');
    }

    /**
     * Get font to use when generating captcha
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFont() {
        $font = (string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('font');
        $fonts = $this->_captchaData->getFonts();

        if (isset($fonts[$font])) {
            $fontPath = $fonts[$font]['path'];
        } else {
            $fontData = array_shift($fonts);
            $fontPath = $fontData['path'];
        }

        return $fontPath;
    }

    /**
     * After this time isCorrect() is going to return FALSE even if word was guessed correctly
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getExpiration() {
        if (!$this->_expiration) {
            /**
             * as "timeout" configuration parameter specifies timeout in minutes - we multiply it on 60 to set
             * expiration in seconds
             */
            $this->_expiration = (int) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('timeout') * 60;
        }
        return $this->_expiration;
    }

    /**
     * Get timeout for session token
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTimeout() {
        return $this->getExpiration();
    }

    /**
     * Get captcha image directory
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImgDir() {
        return $this->_captchaData->getImgDir();
    }

    /**
     * Get captcha image base URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImgUrl() {
        return $this->_captchaData->getImgUrl();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether captcha was guessed correctly by user
     *
     * @param string $word
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCorrect($word) {
        $storedWord = $this->getWord();
        $this->_clearWord();

        if (!$word || !$storedWord) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->isCaseSensitive()) {
            $storedWord = strtolower($storedWord);
            $word = strtolower($word);
        }
        return $word === $storedWord;
    }

    /**
     * Return full URL to captcha image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImgSrc() {
        return $this->getImgUrl() . $this->getId() . $this->getSuffix();
    }

    /**
     * Log attempt
     *
     * @param string $login
     * @return $this
     */
    public function logAttempt($login) {
        if ($this->_isEnabled() && in_array($this->_formId, $this->_getTargetForms())) {
            $this->_getResourceModel()->logAttempt($login);
            if ($this->_isOverLimitLoginAttempts($login)) {
                $this->setShowCaptchaInSession(true);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set show_captcha flag in session
     *
     * @param bool $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setShowCaptchaInSession($value = true) {
        if ($value !== true) {
            $value = false;
        }

        $this->_session->setData($this->_getFormIdKey('show_captcha'), $value);
    }

    /**
     * Generate word used for captcha render
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _generateWord() {
        $word = '';
        $symbols = $this->_getSymbols();
        $wordLen = $this->_getWordLen();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $wordLen; $i++) {
            $word .= $symbols[array_rand($symbols)];
        }
        return $word;
    }

    /**
     * Get symbols array to use for word generation
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSymbols() {
        return str_split((string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('symbols'));
    }

    /**
     * Returns length for generating captcha word. This value may be dynamic.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getWordLen() {
        $from = 0;
        $to = 0;
        $length = (string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('length');
        if (!is_numeric($length)) {
            if (preg_match('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', $length, $matches)) {
                $from = (int) $matches[1];
                $to = (int) $matches[2];
            }
        } else {
            $from = (int) $length;
            $to = (int) $length;
        }

        if ($to < $from || $from < 1 || $to < 1) {
            $from = self::DEFAULT_WORD_LENGTH_FROM;
            $to = self::DEFAULT_WORD_LENGTH_TO;
        }

        return \Magento\Framework\Math\Random::getRandomNumber($from, $to);
    }

    /**
     * Whether to show captcha for this form every time
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isShowAlways() {
        if ((string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('mode') == \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data::MODE_ALWAYS) {
            return true;
        }

        if ((string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig(
                        'mode'
                ) == \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data::MODE_AFTER_FAIL && $this->_getAllowedAttemptsForSameLogin() == 0
        ) {
            return true;
        }

        $alwaysFor = $this->_captchaData->getConfig('always_for');
        foreach ($alwaysFor as $nodeFormId => $isAlwaysFor) {
            if ($isAlwaysFor && $this->_formId == $nodeFormId) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Whether captcha is enabled at this area
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isEnabled() {
        return (string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('enable');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list of forms where captcha must be shown
     *
     * For frontend this list is based on current website
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getTargetForms() {
        $formsString = (string) $this->_captchaData->getConfig('forms');
        return explode(',', $formsString);
    }

    /**
     * Get captcha word
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWord() {
        $sessionData = $this->_session->getData($this->_getFormIdKey(self::SESSION_WORD));
        return time() < $sessionData['expires'] ? $sessionData['data'] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Set captcha word
     *
     * @param  string $word
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _setWord($word) {
        $this->_session->setData(
                $this->_getFormIdKey(self::SESSION_WORD), ['data' => $word, 'expires' => time() + $this->getTimeout()]
        );
        $this->_word = $word;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set captcha word
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _clearWord() {
        $this->_session->unsetData($this->_getFormIdKey(self::SESSION_WORD));
        $this->_word = null;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Override function to generate less curly captcha that will not cut off
     *
     * @see \Zend_Captcha_Image::_randomSize()
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _randomSize() {
        return \Magento\Framework\Math\Random::getRandomNumber(280, 300) / 100;
    }

    /**
     * Overlap of the parent method
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * Now deleting old captcha images make crontab script
     * @see \Magento\Captcha\Cron\DeleteExpiredImages::execute
     */
    protected function _gc() {
        //do nothing
    }

    /**
     * Get resource model
     *
     * @return \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\Log
     */
    protected function _getResourceModel() {
        return $this->_resLogFactory->create();
    }

    protected function _generateImage($id, $word) {
        if (!extension_loaded("gd")) {
            #require_once 'Zend/Captcha/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Captcha_Exception("Image CAPTCHA requires GD extension");
        }

        if (!function_exists("imagepng")) {
            #require_once 'Zend/Captcha/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Captcha_Exception("Image CAPTCHA requires PNG support");
        }

        if (!function_exists("imageftbbox")) {
            #require_once 'Zend/Captcha/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Captcha_Exception("Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support");
        }

        $font = $this->getFont();

        if (empty($font)) {
            #require_once 'Zend/Captcha/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Captcha_Exception("Image CAPTCHA requires font");
        }

        $w = $this->getWidth();
        $h = $this->getHeight();
        $fsize = $this->getFontSize();

        $img_file = $this->getImgDir() . $id . $this->getSuffix();
        if (empty($this->_startImage)) {
            $img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        } else {
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($this->_startImage);
            if (!$img) {
                #require_once 'Zend/Captcha/Exception.php';
                throw new Zend_Captcha_Exception("Can not load start image");
            }
            $w = imagesx($img);
            $h = imagesy($img);
        }
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
        $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $w - 1, $h - 1, $bg_color);
        $textbox = imageftbbox($fsize, 0, $font, $word);
        $x = ($w - ($textbox[2] - $textbox[0])) / 2;
        $y = ($h - ($textbox[7] - $textbox[1])) / 2;
        imagefttext($img, $fsize, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font, $word);

        // generate noise
        /*for ($i = 0; $i < $this->_dotNoiseLevel; $i++) {
            imagefilledellipse($img, mt_rand(0, $w), mt_rand(0, $h), 2, 2, $text_color);
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->_lineNoiseLevel; $i++) {
            imageline($img, mt_rand(0, $w), mt_rand(0, $h), mt_rand(0, $w), mt_rand(0, $h), $text_color);
        }*/

        // transformed image
        $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($img2, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, 0, $w - 1, $h - 1, $bg_color);
        // apply wave transforms
        $freq1 = $this->_randomFreq();
        $freq2 = $this->_randomFreq();
        $freq3 = $this->_randomFreq();
        $freq4 = $this->_randomFreq();

        $ph1 = $this->_randomPhase();
        $ph2 = $this->_randomPhase();
        $ph3 = $this->_randomPhase();
        $ph4 = $this->_randomPhase();

        $szx = $this->_randomSize();
        $szy = $this->_randomSize();

        for ($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++) {
                $sx = $x + (sin($x * $freq1 + $ph1) + sin($y * $freq3 + $ph3)) * $szx;
                $sy = $y + (sin($x * $freq2 + $ph2) + sin($y * $freq4 + $ph4)) * $szy;

                if ($sx < 0 || $sy < 0 || $sx >= $w - 1 || $sy >= $h - 1) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $color = (imagecolorat($img, $sx, $sy) >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    $color_x = (imagecolorat($img, $sx + 1, $sy) >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    $color_y = (imagecolorat($img, $sx, $sy + 1) >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    $color_xy = (imagecolorat($img, $sx + 1, $sy + 1) >> 16) & 0xFF;
                }
                if ($color == 255 && $color_x == 255 && $color_y == 255 && $color_xy == 255) {
                    // ignore background
                    continue;
                } elseif ($color == 0 && $color_x == 0 && $color_y == 0 && $color_xy == 0) {
                    // transfer inside of the image as-is
                    $newcolor = 0;
                } else {
                    // do antialiasing for border items
                    $frac_x = $sx - floor($sx);
                    $frac_y = $sy - floor($sy);
                    $frac_x1 = 1 - $frac_x;
                    $frac_y1 = 1 - $frac_y;

                    $newcolor = $color * $frac_x1 * $frac_y1 + $color_x * $frac_x * $frac_y1 + $color_y * $frac_x1 * $frac_y + $color_xy * $frac_x * $frac_y;
                }
                imagesetpixel($img2, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate($img2, $newcolor, $newcolor, $newcolor));
            }
        }

        // generate noise
        /* for ($i=0; $i<$this->_dotNoiseLevel; $i++) {
          imagefilledellipse($img2, mt_rand(0,$w), mt_rand(0,$h), 2, 2, $text_color);
          }
          for ($i=0; $i<$this->_lineNoiseLevel; $i++) {
          imageline($img2, mt_rand(0,$w), mt_rand(0,$h), mt_rand(0,$w), mt_rand(0,$h), $text_color);
          } */

        imagepng($img2, $img_file);
        imagedestroy($img);
        imagedestroy($img2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, post your code lines: `Custom\Module\Model\DefaultModel.php`?

Comment: HI @KhoaTruongDinh Updated. I think it's dealing with Captcha Model

Comment: HI @KhoaTruongDinh If i remove line from `di.xml` & not calling captcha Model then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You first need to inject the following class in your constructor: `/Magento/Customer/Model/Session` :

```
protected $_session;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_session = $session;
    ...
}

if ($this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {
    // Customer is logged in 
} else {
    // Customer is not logged in
}
```